# EnvDTE SolutionFolder AddFromFile shows error message

Tags: c#, envdte

I want to add some projects to solution using DTE. This is WPF application, not an extension.

I have to add some projects to one folder, and then another one project to other folder and last project to yet another folder.

When adding projects to first folder everything is ok. But when I add projects to another folder, the message box popups saying: "Operation could not be completed: Invalid window handle."

After clicking OK, I get another MessageBox: "Operation could not be completed: Unspecified error".

But, all the projects are successfully added to the solution. So the biggest problem is the message box that popups while doing the job. Having read "invalid window handle", I thought that maybe I should try do EVERYTHING on main thread. But result is the same. Additionaly there is no messages in Output Window of Visual Studio. This is my code:

(DoFunction and DoAction are simple methods that wraps the content into try..catch and if there is RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER exception, it will take another attempt)

```
//Getting DTE Service
dteService = DoFunction(() =>(DTE2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0", true), true));

//Getting the solution
activeSolution = DoFunction(() => dteService.Solution as Solution4);
DoAction(() =>activeSolution.Open(solutionPath));
```

ActiveSolution is my private field.

```
//Adding project to solution:
DoAction(() =>
{
    SolutionFolder folder = GetExistingSolutionFolder(folderTree);
    if (folder == null)
        activeSolution.AddFromFile(projectFileName);
    else
        folder.AddFromFile(projectFileName); //<-- messagebox popups here
});
```

Project is being added to folder inside solution. Folders already exist in solution. GetExistingSolutionFolder just searches recurseviley for the folder.

What could be the reason of this message box?
What's important, no exception is thrown.

Comment: It is a notorious exception that is raised when the machine's desktop heap runs out of space or a process tries to create more than 10,000 windows.  Have a look-see with Task Manager, Processes tab.  Add the USER Objects column.

Comment: This devenv instance uses about 146 user objects and then shows the message box. My devenc instance -> actual Visual Studio uses about 315.

Comment: Event when I quit dteService at the end of first folder and then open it again - it shows a message box.

Comment: What you are trying to do is very obscure, the failure is wonky enough to require Microsoft Support to help you chase this down.  But they'll almost surely tell you that you need to create a VSIX add-in instead.  I'd personally first disable the VS2017 "lightweight solution load" option.  Next I'd startup VS again and attach the debugger to the first instance to try to capture a stack-trace of the exception.  But we don't even know what VS version you use, hard to help you.

Comment: This is VS2017. As I said, there is no exception thrown and nothing useful in call stack.